# How to avoid multiple allocating of CLLocationManager instance?

Tags: iphone, ios5, gps, xcode4.2, core-location

I am using core location framework inside my app and sending updated location to server in didUpdateToLocation method and the view where i am allocating the CLLocationManager instance is the second view after login and this view is called from login view and releasing CLLocationManager in dealloc method but every time i am coming from login screen then didUpdateToLocation method calling twice and thrice depending on how many times i am coming from login view so whats the problem is and how can i avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid multiple allocations of your CLLocationManager instance, define the instance as a property of your `appDelegate`

Each time you need to get this instance you will do

```
YouAppDelegate *appDelegate = (YouAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
appDelegate.yourLocationInstance;
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually just use a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) for this type of thing. Just define a class method (using a + vs a - on the method definition). Here's an example of a singleton definition:

```
+(id)sharedLocationManager
{
static BCLocationManager *sharedLocationManager;
@synchronized(self)
{
    if (!sharedLocationManager)
    {
        sharedLocationManager = [[BCLocationManager alloc] init];
    }

    return sharedLocationManager;
}
return sharedLocationManager;
}
```

Basically you define a static instance of your class and only initialize it if it doesn't exist. With a singleton, you never access the instance init function. Always assign the result of the singleton accessor to the appropriate pointer like so:

```
BCLocationManager * testInstance = [BCLocationManager sharedLocationManager];
```

Now all you have to do is include the appropriate header.h and everyone in your application can see that single instance of your location manager. As long as you don't use an instance of init, you'll never create more than one.